# jquery height() method returns line-height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following function in which i have three columns.  The javascript should find the largest column and set the height of the other columns to that height.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    function fixScheduleHeights(){
        content1 = $('.schedule_content_holder').first();
        content2 = content1.next();
        content3 = content2.next();

        content1Height = content1.height();
        content2Height = content2.height();
        content3Height = content3.height();

        biggestScheduleHeight = Math.max(content1Height, content2Height, content3Height);

        $('.schedule_content_holder').height(biggestScheduleHeight);
    }
    fixScheduleHeights();
});
```

I tried the code above and it works if the largest column is the first column.  it does not work if the longest column is the second column.  I put the following code in for debugging purposes:

```
alert(content2height);
```

and it alerted the value of 16, which should not be the value of content2height.  After looking in the inspector, I figured out that the problem is that body has a css property of line-height: 16px;

Why is content2Height = 16 and how do I change it so that it is equal to the actual height?

Comment: is `.schedule_content_holder` an inline element?

Comment: `height()` does not return line-height, so if it says 16px, it's 16px.  Also note that all your variables are global

Comment: almost seems like the content that the ajax is meant to load is not loaded yet

Comment: Are you sure that `content1.next()` is returning the next column? Can you post your markup?

Comment: Styling has such an impact of height, you really need to post some HTML and CCS (preferably in a JSFiddle).

Comment: To use height(), you should know this method has 2 sisters: innerHeight() and outerHeight(). Globally, i use outerHeight() (inner height + padding + border) more often than height().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a simpler, most robust way to do what you're doing, that does not depend on the position or number of your columns, because I think your calls to `.next()` are not returning what you think they're returning. `next()` returns the next sibling in the DOM tree (optionally filtered by selector, and you're not providing one). You could be returning a `<br />`, an `<span>` or anything else.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    var $columns = $('.schedule_content_holder');
    var maxHeight = 0;

    $columns.each(function() {
         maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, $(this).height());
    });

    $columns.height(maxHeight);
});
```